# Accurate catalogue of the Stars according to Hemisphere

Tags: software, star-catalogues, astronomy-site

I am in the need for an accurate catalogue of the stars in the Hemisphere I am currently in (or the one that I chose) and their positions at any time of the year.

The more accurate the catalogue is, the better. I don't want any live-time-location app, but a simple place whence I can refer where a star or any other celestial object is.

### What do you mean by a 'live-time-location app'?

To answer this question asked by @DrChuck in the comments below, I will take the example of an Android app called 'Skymap'. This app takes your live location and uses the phone's internal compass to determine what direction the phone is pointed in, and shows the celestial objects (visible/non-visible) in the direction according to the time-settings of your phone.

### What data are you looking for?

Another question asked by @DrChuck in the comments below. I am looking for the following info :-

- Catalogue of all stars visible from all over the Hemisphere.
- Their respective positions.
- Catalogue of other celestial objects like Galaxies, etc.
- Special events like Solar Eclipses visible from the Hemisphere.*
- Position of any celestial body during any time in the future or past.*
  (*  - Not necessary)

### Um, can we make things, well, *simpler?*

Some things listed below are really not necessary :-

- It does not matter if it does not list the objects that cannot be seen through the naked eye.
- It does not have to be really complicated. Anything a normal person can use is fine.

P.S. - Any help with any appropriate tags for this question will also be appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by live-time-location app; and what data are you looking for?

Comment: @DrChuck - I have edited the question to include *a very specific and detailed* description of what you have asked for. Hope that helps?

Comment: Perhaps the answers to one of these questions may help : https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/22802/9527 https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/18191/9527 https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/3668/9527

Comment: @InfinityMilestone You introduced the tag [tag:astronomy-site] and I have troubles figuring out how you define that. Maybe you could help me with that, please?

Comment: @B--rian, thanks for reminding me! I completely forgot that I haven't added a Tag-wiki to it. :P Since I don't have the privilege of immediately-accepted Tag-wikis, I submitted a proposal just now. And now we wait...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that astronomers generally are not concerned with hemispheres, so it is unlikely that you will find a catalog that is only for a specific hemisphere. Catalog generally cover the entire sky. Also, most catalogs are for either stars or deep sky objects (galaxies, nebulae, and so on). I have not seen a catalog that includes both stellar and non-stellar.

For stars, I suggest the [Yale Bright Star Catalog](http://tdc-www.harvard.edu/catalogs/bsc5.html). It includes around 9000 stars, some of which are slightly too faint to see with the naked eye.

For nonstellar objects, I suggest the [NGC Catalog](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/W3Browse/all/ngc2000.html).